# reliable mp3 playback in python with documentation

Tags: library, software-development, python, mp3

I am looking for a package or library that can playback mp3's in python and is well documented. gstreamer could do the job, but I don't understand the python bindings. pygame is straight forward but will not play back mp3 reliably on mac lin and PC from what I've heard.

Comment: Is the set of MP3s you want to play fixed? If so, you could just convert them to a format that pygame likes better.

Comment: @Kodiologist no, they files are user input. [https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/47342/python-media-libary-to-develop-a-soundboard-ambient-mixer](see my other question) if you, however know a good way of reencoding mp3's I'd might look into that as well